# Using COUNT Function in Table Joins

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am writing a sql code for a report page that that joins three tables. Here is the query I have written.

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT Count(DISTINCT Courses.CourseID) AS CourseCount, Count(DISTINCT Students.StudentID) AS StudentCount, Count(Students.StartDate) AS StartCount, School.Name, School.StartDate, School.SchoolFees " +
                "FROM Schools " +
                "LEFT JOIN Courses ON (School.SchoolID = Courses.SchoolId) " +
                "LEFT JOIN Students ON (School.SchoolID = Student.SchoolID) " +
                "WHERE School.Active = 1 " +
                "GROUP BY School.Name, School.StartDate, School.SchoolFees";
```

The above query works well. But I want to show the count of the Student.StartDate for each School where Student.StartDate satisfy a condition. Here is the query I want to use

```
SELECT Count(Students.StartDate)
FROM Students
WHERE Student.StartDate >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE());
```

I want the above query to be return as part of my main query but dont know how to achieve it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want aggregates from different tables, you should not join the tables and then aggregate, but always build the aggregates first and join these instead. In your case you were able to avoid issues by counting distinct IDs, but that is not always possible (i.e. when looking for sums or avarages). You can count conditionally with `CASE WHEN`.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(c.CourseCount, 0) AS CourseCount,
  COALESCE(s.StudentCount, 0) AS StudentCount,
  COALESCE(s.StartCount, 0) AS StartCount,
  School.Name, 
  School.StartDate, 
  School.SchoolFees
FROM Schools
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT SchoolID, COUNT(*) AS CourseCount
  FROM Courses 
  GROUP BY SchoolID
) c ON c.SchoolId = School.SchoolID
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SchoolID, 
    COUNT(*) AS StudentCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN StartDate >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE() THEN 1 END) as StartCount
  FROM Students 
  GROUP BY SchoolID
) s ON s.SchoolId = School.SchoolID
WHERE School.Active = 1;
```

In case it is guaranteed for every school to have at least one student and one course (which is probably the case), you can change the outer joins to inner joins and get thus rid of the COALESCE expressions.

Comment: Your answer was very useful and informative. I learnt something new. Thanks alot. I got a little question. When getting rid of the COALESCE expression, does that mean I just have "SELECT CourseCount, StudentCount.....".

Comment: @elfico: Yes, exactly. When selecting data from different tables, I use table qualifiers to show where the columns stem from - even when the column names should be descriptive enough: `SELECT c.CourseCount, s.StudentCount, s.StartCount, ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  Just add this to the `SELECT`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Student.StartDate >= DATEADD(month,-1, GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as RecentStudents
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I tried it and it worked, but the sum was less 1. I was expecting 21 but got 20. Used the answer by @Kettner and got the right answer. Learnt something new thought. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `CASE WHEN` , you can solve this,

```
SELECT  Count(DISTINCT Courses.CourseID)    AS  CourseCount, 
        Count(DISTINCT Students.StudentID)  AS  StudentCount, 
        Count(Students.StartDate) AS StartCount, 
        Sum(CASE WHEN Student.StartDate >= DATEADD(month,-1, GETDATE()) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS  StartDateCount ,
        School.Name, School.StartDate, School.SchoolFees
FROM Schools
LEFT JOIN Courses ON (School.SchoolID = Courses.SchoolId)
LEFT JOIN Students ON (School.SchoolID = Student.SchoolID)
WHERE School.Active = 1
GROUP BY School.Name, School.StartDate, School.SchoolFees
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I tried it and it worked, but the sum was less 1. I was expecting 21 but got 20. Used the answer by @Kettner and got the right answer. Learnt something new thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this helps

```
   myConnect.Open();
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT Count(DISTINCT Courses.CourseID) AS CourseCount, Count(DISTINCT Students.StudentID) AS StudentCount, Count(Students.StartDate) AS StartCount, School.Name, School.StartDate, School.SchoolFees, " +
        "(SELECT Count(stu.StartDate) FROM Students stu WHERE School.SchoolID = stu.SchoolID AND stu.StartDate >= DATEADD(month,-1, GETDATE())) AS CountStartDate" + // your count
        "FROM Schools " +
        "LEFT JOIN Courses ON (School.SchoolID = Courses.SchoolId) " +
        "LEFT JOIN Students ON (School.SchoolID = Student.SchoolID) " +
        "WHERE School.Active = 1 " +
        "GROUP BY School.Name, School.StartDate, School.SchoolFees";
```

Comment: It didnt work. I used the answer by @kettner and it worked. Thanks for the help though.